# Given two numbers, return true if any one of them divides the other, else return false

Tags: java

Given two numbers, return true if any one of them divides the other, else return false

```
public class DividesAB {

static int testcase11 = 208;
static int testcase12 = 7;
boolean aDivisblebyb, bDivisblebya, answer;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DividesAB testInstance = new DividesAB();
        boolean result = testInstance.divides(testcase11,testcase12);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public boolean divides(int a, int b){
        boolean aDivisiblebyb = a%b == 0;
        boolean bdivisiblebya = b%a == 0;
        boolean answer = aDivisiblebyb||bDivisiblebya;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I have been getting errors like `cannot find symbol`

Comment: If you want help you really should explain your problem better. Best to explain your logic and what you have tried.

Comment: ... or just learn how to read and understand compiler errors (which tell you the exact line number that contains the error).

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess of code thrown together and half it it isn't needed.  To find if a symbol is not defined, look at the line of code in your IDE where it is complaining and see why that variable is not in scope.

If you only write the code you need, there is less chance of making a mistake, and it is easier to see where the mistake is.

This is how I would write it

```
public class DividesAB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 208, b = 7;
        System.out.printf("a: %,d divides b: %,d is %s%n", divides(a, b));
    }

    //write your code here
    public static boolean divides(int a, int b){
        return a % b == 0 || b % a == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable names are not correct.

> aDivisblebyb and you are using aDivisiblebyb

So change the variable names and it should work.

Comment: sorry that was a spelling mistake, but the above program does not work for values a=1296, b=7776. it works for some values but not for some

Answer (score 0):

First, look at the "cannot find symbol" error from your compiler.  It should tell you exactly what line the error is occurring on, and most likely the exact error that is occurring.  In your case, it will point to:

```
boolean answer = aDivisiblebyb||bDivisiblebya;
```

In your declaration, the spelling is different (`aDivisblebyb` vs `aDivisiblebyb`), so the compiler does not understand what the symbol `aDivisiblebyb` is.  Same goes for `aDivisiblebya`.  Hence the error.

Side note:  you have declared `boolean aDivisblebyb` and `boolean bDivisblebya` in two places.  In the code you posted, it is unnecessary to access these boolean values outside of the `divides` method (same with the `answer` boolean).  So, to clean it up a little:

```
public class DividesAB {

    static int testcase11 = 208;
    static int testcase12 = 7;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DividesAB testInstance = new DividesAB();
        boolean result = testInstance.divides(testcase11,testcase12);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public boolean divides(int a, int b){
        boolean aDivisiblebyb = a%b == 0;
        boolean bDivisiblebya = b%a == 0;
        boolean answer = aDivisiblebyb||bDivisiblebya;
        return answer;
    }
}
```